# python program. apple asking machine

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been trying to create a trouble shooting system any my code works fine in the begging but I can't seem to find the problem as it stops working.

```
print("welcome to Apple online iPhone help system, I will ask you a series of questions and please answer with a 'yes' or 'no', if by the end our automatic troubleshooting system does not help you,there are more support and help options available on our website https://getsupport.apple.com/ ") 
q1 = input("Is your phone running slow?")
if q1 == "yes" :
        print("ou need to free up space, phones slow down when they are full, try deleting unused apps or unnecessary photos or buy more storage. If that doesn’t fix your problem contact Apple for more help.")

if q1== "no":
                print("okay let's move on to the next question")
                q2 = input ("have your dropped your phone in water?")
                if q2 == "yes":
                            print ("turn off your phone and leave your phone in a bag of rice for 72 hours and after the waiting periodturn it on and it should work, if it doesn't your phone is broken, contact apple to get it fixed")

                            if q2 == "no":# after this code it stops working i do not understand why.
                                    print ("okay let's move on to the next question")
                                    q3 = input ("Does your phone keep crashing?")
                                    if q3 == "yes":
                                                print ("Reset your phone and that should prevent your phone from crashing, If that doesn’t fix your problem contact Apple for more help.")
                                                if q3 == "no":
                                                        print("okay let's move on to the next question")
                                                        q4 = input("is your promblem due to the recent update?")
                                                        if q4 == "yes":
                                                                    print ("there could be multiple soulitions to the this problem, go to 'www.apple.suppot/recentupdate.com and find your problem")
                                                                    if q4 == "no":
                                                                            print ("okay let's move on to the next question")
```

---

When I run the program this happens:

> welcome to Apple online iPhone help system, I will ask you a series of questions and please answer with a 'yes' or 'no', if by the end our automatic troubleshooting system does not help you,there are more support and help options available on our website https://getsupport.apple.com/
>   Is your phone running slow?no
>   okay let's move on to the next question
>   have your dropped your phone in water?no

It doesn't ask the next question why?

Comment: Use elif and dont get the indentation wrong

Comment: Welcome to programming Maryam! Your code reminds me of something the cat dragged in a month ago, although the blood might be in my eyes this time.

Comment: I would really recommend storing the questions and answers in a file (3 lines for each question: question, answer if yes, answer if no). Then you can just write a loop that reads the file (3 lines every time), prints the appropriate one and jumps to the next question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Check your indentation.

```
if q2 == "no":
```

is indented wrongly. The same happens for the rest.  Also, it would be better to use `if-elif`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the correct version of your code:

```
print("welcome to Apple online iPhone help system, I will ask you a series of questions and please answer with a 'yes' or 'no', if by the end our automatic troubleshooting system does not help you,there are more support and help options available on our website https://getsupport.apple.com/ ") 
q1 = input("Is your phone running slow?")
if q1 == "yes" :
    print("You need to free up space, phones slow down when they are full, try deleting unused apps or unnecessary photos or buy more storage. If that doesn’t fix your problem contact Apple for more help.")
elif q1 == "no":
    print("okay let's move on to the next question")
    q2 = input ("have your dropped your phone in water?")
    if q2 == "yes":
                print ("turn off your phone and leave your phone in a bag of rice for 72 hours and after the waiting periodturn it on and it should work, if it doesn't your phone is broken, contact apple to get it fixed")

    elif q2 == "no":
            print ("okay let's move on to the next question")
            q3 = input ("Does your phone keep crashing?")
            if q3 == "yes":
                        print ("Reset your phone and that should prevent your phone from crashing, If that doesn’t fix your problem contact Apple for more help.")
            elif q3 == "no":
                    print("okay let's move on to the next question")
                    q4 = input("is your promblem due to the recent update?")
                    if q4 == "yes":
                                print ("there could be multiple soulitions to the this problem, go to 'www.apple.suppot/recentupdate.com and find your problem")
                                if q4 == "no":
                                        print ("okay let's move on to the next question")
```

Use `elif` blocks to manage your logic flow.

Your code has the `else` functionality within the `if` blocks so they will never execute.

Answer (score 0):

I would dispense with the test for the answers being "no", you don't have any contingency for any answer other than "yes" or "no" anyhow.   For example:

```
print("welcome to Apple online iPhone help system, I will ask you a series of questions and please answer with a 'yes' or 'no', if by the end our automatic troubleshooting system does not help you,there are more support and help options available on our website https://getsupport.apple.com/ ")

q1 = input("Is your phone running slow? ")
if q1 == "yes" :
    print("you need to free up space, phones slow down when they are full, try deleting unused apps or unnecessary photos or buy more storage. If that doesn’t fix your problem contact Apple for more help.")

else:
    print("okay let's move on to the next question")
    q2 = input("have your dropped your phone in water? ")
    if q2 == "yes":
        print ("turn off your phone and leave your phone in a bag of rice for 72 hours and after the waiting periodturn it on and it should work, if it doesn't your phone is broken, contact apple to get it fixed")

    else:            
        print("okay let's move on to the next question")
        q3 = input("Does your phone keep crashing? ")
        if q3 == "yes":
            print ("Reset your phone and that should prevent your phone from crashing, If that doesn’t fix your problem contact Apple for more help.")
        else:
            print("okay let's move on to the next question")
            q4 = input("is your problem due to the recent update? ")
            if q4 == "yes":
                print("there could be multiple solutions to the this problem, go to 'www.apple.support/recentupdate.com and find your problem")
            else:
                print("okay let's move on to the next question")
```

However we can make the code easier to maintain by using a list.  Also note that adjacent strings are concatenated - you don't need those really long lines that are difficult to edit.

For example:

```
print("Welcome to Apple online iPhone help system, I will ask you a series "
      "of questions and please answer with a 'yes' or 'no', if by the end "
      "our automatic troubleshooting system does not help you,there are more "
      "support and help options available on our website "
      "https://getsupport.apple.com/ \n")

q_and_a = [
         ["Is your phone running slow? ",
          "You need to free up space, phones slow down when they are full,"  
          " try deleting unused apps or unnecessary photos or buy more storage."
          " If that doesn’t fix your problem contact Apple for more help."],

         ["Have your dropped your phone in water? ",
          "turn off your phone and leave it in a bag of rice for 72 hours "
          "and after the waiting periodturn it on and it should work, if it "
          "doesn't your phone is broken, contact Apple to get it fixed"],

         ["Does your phone keep crashing? ",
          "Reset your phone and that should prevent your phone from crashing. "
          "If that doesn’t fix your problem contact Apple for more help."],

         ["Is your problem due to the recent update? ",
          "There could be multiple solutions to the this problem, "
          "go to 'www.apple.support/recentupdate.com and find your problem"],

          ]

def askit(question):
    retn = False

    ans = input(question[0])
    if ans == "yes":
        print(question[1])
        retn = True
    else:
        print("\nOkay let's move on to the next question")

    return retn

for q in q_and_a:
    if askit(q):
        break
```

Comment: if the answer is yes, you could then `return`. This way the next code is not executed so you actually don't need an else and you will save a lot of indentation.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: We don't know that this is in a function, or is stand-alone.  Generally it is considered bad-practice to have more then one return.

Comment: on a standalone code you can use exit. I don't agree it's always bad practice. In this case makes the code less indented and more clear. Sometimes returning early saves you from carrying conditions to the end of the function.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: OK, we will have to disagree on that, in my opinion that is spaghetti code.  I assume you mean `sys.exit()`, since `exit()` should not be used in a script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your code inside a function, then can use `return` at the end of the "yes" condition to prevent the rest of the code from executing.

If your code is not inside a function you can use `sys.exit()` instead.

This way you can skip the else clauses and prevent increasing indentation.

```
def main():
    print("welcome to Apple online iPhone help system, I will ask you a series of questions and please answer with a 'yes' or 'no', if by the end our automatic troubleshooting system does not help you,there are more support and help options available on our website https://getsupport.apple.com/ ")

    q1 = input("Is your phone running slow? ")
    if q1 == "yes" :
        print("you need to free up space, phones slow down when they are full, try deleting unused apps or unnecessary photos or buy more storage. If that doesn’t fix your problem contact Apple for more help.")
        return

    print("okay let's move on to the next question")
    q2 = input("have your dropped your phone in water? ")
    if q2 == "yes":
        print("turn off your phone and leave your phone in a bag of rice for 72 hours and after the waiting periodturn it on and it should work, if it doesn't your phone is broken, contact apple to get it fixed")
        return

    print("okay let's move on to the next question")
    q3 = input("Does your phone keep crashing? ")
    if q3 == "yes":
    print("Reset your phone and that should prevent your phone from crashing, If that doesn’t fix your problem contact Apple for more help.")
        return

    print("okay let's move on to the next question")
    q4 = input("is your problem due to the recent update? ")
    if q4 == "yes":
        print("there could be multiple solutions to the this problem, go to 'www.apple.support/recentupdate.com and find your problem")
        return         

    print("okay let's move on to the next question")
    # the rest of your questions/answers


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: 'return' is a outside function. how do i fix that? @sembeiNORIMAKI

Comment: If your code is not inside a function, use `sys.exit()` instead of return (first you will have to `import sys`). Another option is putting your code inside a function and using return. I edited my code to use a function that you can call.